# Anaconda install keras-tuner in tensorflow environment

Tags: tensorflow, keras, anaconda, anaconda3, keras-tuner

I am using Anaconda 3 and would like to install keras-tuner in the tensorflow environment.
I've tried

*conda install -c conda-forge keras-tuner*

in the Anaconda Prompt (see https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/keras-tuner) which worked fine. However, the package has been installed in the base environment (and not in the tensorflow environment).
How can I choose the environment in which I want to install keras-tuner?
I use tensorflow 2.1.0 on a Windows machine

Comment: conda install --name tensorflow -c conda-forge keras-tuner

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of doing it.

1. activating the target environment and running the same command.
2. You can install a conda package also without activating the environment. Just use

```
conda install -n <env_name> <package> or conda install -p <path/to/env> <package>
```